# group list of list into a map in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in javascript to group a list of list into a map? I can easily do it in groovy using groupby for example

```
    def group = [['1', '44'], ['2', '55'], ['3','42']].groupBy {it.get(0)}
```

would result into:
[1:[[1, 44]], 2:[[2, 55]], 3:[[3, 42]]]

I am new to javascript and not sure if groupby is supported by Rhino 1.7 R4

Answer (score 0):

Generally you don't need groupby in javascript. As I can assume that you need index of each element.

```
var arr = [['1', '44'], ['2', '55'], ['3','42']];
```

Javascript arr already index and can be accessible by

```
var result = arr[0]
console.log(result) // ['1', '44']
```

Like so on. But if you want to achieve anything else to make it index. Please post it more clarity what you need.

Still its not clear what you want to achieve it here but just for your reference

```
let group = [['1', '44'], ['2', '55'], ['3','42']];

let newGroup = [];

for(let i = 0; i<group.length; i++){
    newGroup[i+1] = group[i]
}

console.log(newGroup)
```

Output will be same as you mentioned.

Comment: Hello, I need to group them together based on a specific index, the above was just an example for simple illustration

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want in pure javascript then you can loop the group array and add each element into a map with it's index.
Example:

```
let group = [['1', '44'], ['2', '55'], ['3','42']];

let newGroup = {};

for(let i = 0; i<group.length; i++){
    newGroup[i+1] = group[i]
}

console.log(newGroup)
```